# Selector to check selected value of all drop down lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, selector

I'm trying to find a way to check wether the value selected of all my drop down lists `!=''` using just one selector in JQuery.

Instead of :

```
if ($("#list1").val() != '' && $("#list2").val() != ''
            && $('#list3').val() != '' && $('#list4').val() != '') {
//do stuff
}
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to those elements and code:

```
var vals = $('select.lists').map(function() { 
   return this.value;
}).get().join('');

if ( vals != '' ) {
   // ...
}
```